# Authenticating a WCF web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, rest, wcf-security

We have a WCF RESTful service running and working great on IIS 7.  Our users access it through some calls from our MVC3 website, which is on a separate web server and uses forms authentication.

We'd like to make things a bit more secure so that not just anyone can call the methods on the service; only those who are authenticated in the MVC website should make those calls successfully.  Suggestions on how to limit web service calls in this way are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable forms authentication on the WCF service side as shown in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx) (by enabling `ASP.Net Compatibility Mode`). Make sure that both the client (MVC application) and the server use the same machineKeys so that an authentication cookie generated by the MVC application would still be valid for the WCF service. Then when calling the REST method, simply attach the actual client authentication cookie to the request.

Answer (score 1):

here is some links:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149738/Basic-Authentication-on-a-WCF-REST-Service
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162726/Digest-Authentication-on-a-WCF-REST-Serv

I prefer the first way using Auth protocol instead of modifying the HTTP headers.